# How XAML through binding listbox to northwind database

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, listbox

Is there any sample that uses xml for binding a `ListBox` to the northwind database?
For example I want to bind my `ListBox` using the northwind database.  I have norhtwind.mdb file
so how I can bind `ListBox` in only xml please tell me thanks.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ItemsSource-Property of the ListBox.

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource xmlFileRes}, Path=/doc/element, Mode=OneWay}/>
```